# Magento 2.2.5 Data Migration Tool

Tags: magento2, data-migration

I am having the below 2 issues, I disabled the EAV Step, only to be hit with another error (the EAV Step issue)

I am using a fresh Magento 2 database to test this, I am using Magento migration tool 2.2.5, trying to migrate from magento 1.9.3.2

**EAV Step Issue**

`[Exception]
  Notice: Undefined offset: 141 in /vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 813`

**Map Step Issue**

`[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'row_id' in 'field list'`

Any help please?

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed the EAV Step issue, just be the Map Step issue now

Comment: How did you fixed the : Notice: Undefined offset: 141 in /vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 813... i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

Simply change line 58 in /*vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Handler/Gallery/InsertValueToEntity.php*

`: 'row_id';`

to:

`: 'entity_id';`